# How do I import Polymer elements into code playgrounds like plunker (plnkr.co), jsBin and jsFiddle?

Tags: polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0, plunker

**Question:**

In [this Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/gZR0MQ7NXXlaSknukL1i?p=preview), I want to import the Polymer 1.0 elements `<paper-button>` and `<paper-menu>`.

How do I do that?

In other words, what is the proper set of `<script>` and `<link>` tags and their respective `src` and `href` attributes that will allow my `<paper-button>` and `<paper-menu>` elements to properly function?

**Attempts:**

In the right margin, there is an option to search and import external libraries. I used that to search for Polymer 1.0 and I imported the following.

```
<script data-require="polymer@1.0.0" data-semver="1.0.0" src="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/samples/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<script data-require="polymer@1.0.0" data-semver="1.0.0" src="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/samples/components/polymer/polymer.html"></script>
```

Note: [Here is a JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/rayasoquca/edit?html,output) that imports Polymer elements.

Comment: you are importing a html document as a script. you need to use html imports. <link href="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/samples/components/polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Example here](http://jsbin.com/qewedoqito/1/edit?html,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Polymer Bin</title>
  <base href="http://element-party.xyz/">
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="all-elements.html">
</head>
<body class="fullbleed layout vertical">
<x-element></x-element>
<dom-module id="x-element">
  <template>
    <style>...</style>
    <!-- Element markup goes here -->  
  </template>
  <script>
    (function(){
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-element'
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this cdn to import your elements/scripts:
https://github.com/Download/polymer-cdn

so, your imports would be (dependent on the version you would like to use):

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.4/lib/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>

<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.4/lib/paper-button/paper-button.html" />
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.4/lib/paper-menu/paper-menu.html" />
```

If you just need a reference to polymer for your component then import this:

```
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.4/lib/polymer/polymer.html" />
```

This is working in plunker for me.